# How to add a section to an ini file using apache commons configuration 2?

Tags: java, apache, configuration, ini

Apache commons configuration 2 allows to read section of *.ini file. But why doesn't exist methods for writing the section?

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/INIConfiguration.html#getSection-java.lang.String-) of `INIConfiguration.getSection(String name)` says:

> This method never throws an exception. **If the section does not exist, it is created now.** The configuration returned in this case is empty.

A new section will be automatically created in-memory when calling `getSection(...)` and be written to the file whenever you add/modify a property within it using `addProperty(...)` or `setProperty(...)` methods.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but there was another problem. I can't write many values for one key. Therefore this code doesn't work.

SubnodeConfiguration sectionConfig = iniConfig.getSection(SECTION_NAME);
sectionConfig.setListDelimiterHandler(new DefaultListDelimiterHandler(','));
sectionConfig.addProperty("key", stringArray);

Comment: Look like the way `listDelimiterHandler` is used in INIConfiguration's `read` and `write` methods is not consistent. It will always write collections as a separate _key=value_ lines even if you have a delimiter handler set up. I think you should go ahead and submit a PR/Issue for this - https://github.com/apache/commons-configuration